# ipython notebook Markdown Escaping for a filename containing a parenthesis

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I have a file name of "CS20(NF-XXXXX)" and I am not able to escape the second parenthesis with a ")" which I think is supported by markdown. Here is the markdown line -

```
[CS NF-39237](http://collaboration.us.AAAAA.corp/CS(NF-39237).pdf)
```

Here the link is closed off by the first ")" instead of the last. And, adding a "(" and a ")" around the parenthesis in the pdf filename above does not seem to make a difference. What is the correct syntax for esacping a parenthesis?

Comment: I guess this meta SO post can apply : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses

Comment: Thanks Matt. Using %28 for "(" and %29 for ")" works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -

```
http://collaboration.us.AAAAA.corp/CS%28NF-39237%29.pdf
```

provides the desired result. Thanks to Matt for providing link to helpful post above.